# Route gaming data over wireless and everything else through LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, routing

I have two internet connections available to me. One is via LAN. Not a great ping, but fast downloads. The other is via USB wireless adapter. Good ping, but slow downloads. I want to connect to both of them simultaneously. I want to be able to specify which data or application will use the wireless connection and route everything else through the lan connection.

Is this possible, and how would I do it?

Windows 7 x64 is my operating system.

Here is the data from route print: http://pastebin.com/vsjQRpSM

I'm still unsure of how to use this to make all of my data go through the Nvidia lan interface, even after reading route /?

Also, if I'm able to achieve that, will it override the ForceBindIP?

Comment: While the below suggestion of ForceBindIP will allow me to force my gaming data over the wireless connection, how do the rest of my data go over the LAN connection?  Windows 7 seems to just use whichever connection is enabled last.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**ForceBindIP**](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/). Bind the executable of the game to the wireless interface and you should be set.

Additional Information:

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows
>   application that will inject itself
>   into another application and alter how
>   certain Windows Sockets calls are
>   made, allowing you to force the other
>   application to use a specific network
>   interface / IP address. This is useful
>   if you are in an environment with
>   multiple interfaces and your
>   application has no such option for
>   binding to a specific interface.

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks.  If anyone else has another alternative, please post it.  I'd like to know all of my options.

Comment: See my added comment.

Comment: @Alex Windows will follow your routing table. In command line type `route print` to see the current table. `route /?` will show you examples of how to modify the host routing table so all other traffic goes through the wired interface.

Comment: See my added detail.

Answer (score 2):

1. clear persistent routes:

   ```
   route delete 0.0.0.0
   ```
2. Add ethernet as your default connection:

   ```
   route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 [Gateway of Ethernet] metric 9 if 11
   ```
3. Add wifi as your failsafe connection:

   ```
   route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 [Gateway of Wireless] metric 19 if 16
   ```
4. Route specific traffic to wifi:

   ```
   route -p add 99.99.99.0 mask 255.255.255.0 [Gateway of Wireless] metric 2 if 16
   ```

Replace the first 3 octets of 99.99.99.0 with the IP of your gameserver. The mask may need changing depending on your setup. I fiddled around with this today and this is how I got it working. `forcebindip` works somewhat on Windows 7 64-bit if you run it through the 32-bit commandline located at `C:\Windows\syswow64\cmd.exe`. I couldn't get it to be stable on Firefox 3.6 (or any other app for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your default gateway metrics. (From you pastebin) The two lines in question:

```
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1     192.168.2.46     25
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.15.1     192.168.15.2     20
```

It's going to prefer the route with the lowest metric. You can change this with the `route` command, but there is also a windows to change adapter priority.

1. Go to "Network And Sharing Center" (easiest way is to click on the icon in the system tray).
2. On the left side click on "Change Adapter Settings".
3. Press ALT to bring up the Menu Bar
4. Under "Advanced" choose "Advanced Settings..."
5. On the "Adapters and Bindings" tab and under "Connections" you can change the order of priority for your adapters.